# Rails 3.1 asset pipeline outside view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I am trying to set CarrierWave's default url inside of the CarrierWave uploader. To do this, I would like to use the asset pipeline to do the following in `uploaders/image_uploader.rb`:
     def default_url
       image_path('question_mark.png')
     end

But it fails because: `undefined method`image_path' for :ImageUploader`

Then I tried to add `include ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper` to `uploaders/image_uploader.rb` but got this error: `undefined local variable or method`config' for :ImageUploader`

Any idea how I can get the `image_path` helper to work outside the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636204/how-to-use-sass-rails-helpers-in-ruby) and concluded there is no way to get any `*_path` or `*_url` helpers working in models. I knew that it definitely *shouldn't* be done (violating MVC and so forth) but it seems it cannot be done at all...

My problem was setting the `default_url` for a Paperclip attachment and I ended up setting it to the path I would give to `image_tag` (simply `'image.png'` if `image.png` is located in `app/assets/images` or `public/images`) and then using `image_path` when accessing it. Would that work for you as well?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what I was trying to do here, ended up working around it but in case anyone comes here wanting to add the _path or _url helpers in their model, do this:

```rb
class Post < ActiveRecord :: Base
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  # This is so you can use _url params
  # you'll need to define the host in your config for it to work though
  default_url_options[:host] = Rails.configuration.host

  # ...

end
```

Comment: Rails.application.routes.url_helpers should be used for generating URLs defined in routes.rb, not image URLs

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I resolved it by doing the following in Rails 3.2.

I declared the following module:

```
module MyApp::AssetHelper
  def config
    @config ||= ActionController::Base.config
    @config.asset_host = 'http://whereveryouhostyour.assets' #not needed if you have this defined in your environment file
    @config
  end

  def controller
    ActionController::Base
  end
end
```

I included the following helpers into the model where I wanted to use the asset_tag helpers

```
include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
include MyApp::AssetHelper
```

This allowed me to call the asset_tag helpers where I needed it.