# How to use sass-rails helpers in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass, asset-pipeline

From the [Github page](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails) it would seem that one can use the Sass helpers (`asset_path`, `asset_url`, `image_path` etc.) in Ruby but I can't figure out how.

I need to set the `default_url` for a Paperclip attachment and want to use one of my assets from the asset pipeline for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the sass helpers in SCSS files, but you cannot use them elsewhere. In those cases you need to use the regular asset_path and image_tag helpers.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately those helpers dont work in models. I ended up defining the default_url as `paperclip_processing_images/...` and then using `image_path(product.image)` in views and helpers where I use the images.